# How to check if a key in a Map starts with a given String value

Tags: java, string, dictionary

I'm looking for a method like:

```
myMap.containsKeyStartingWith("abc"); // returns true if there's a key starting with "abc" e.g. "abcd"
```

or

```
MapUtils.containsKeyStartingWith(myMap, "abc"); // same
```

I wondered if anyone knew of a simple way to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This can be done with a standard [`SortedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html):

```
Map<String,V> tailMap = myMap.tailMap(prefix);
boolean result = (!tailMap.isEmpty() && tailMap.firstKey().startsWith(prefix));
```

Unsorted maps (e.g. `HashMap`) don't intrinsically support prefix lookups, so for those you'll have to iterate over all keys.

Comment: As I'm using a hashmap i gather i can make a tree map by the following:  
`TreeMap treeMap = new TreeMap();  
treeMap.putAll(hashMap);`

Comment: @Edd: Or, even simpler, `TreeMap<K,V> treeMap = new TreeMap<K,V>(hashMap);`

Answer (score 3):

From the map, you can get a Set of Keys, and in case they are String, you can iterate over the elements of the Set and check for `startsWith("abc")`

Comment: thanks, I can see this would work although i was hoping i wouldn't have to iterate through the key set

Comment: @Edd Why not? It is optimized by java guys to be used this way;)

Comment: it results in higher cyclomatic complexity unless you pull it into a separate method and i have no obvious class to put such a method in so i was hoping i wouldn't need to create a new utility class for maps with a single method in... sounds like i'm being lazy when i say that but it would help if there happened to be a ready made utility method for this... wishful thinking ;)

Comment: Iterating over the map keys is less efficient: it's O(N). A sorted map can do much better: O(log N).

Comment: @martiell but he did not specify what kind of map he's using

Comment: @AdelBoutros Sure, but it also doesn't say what other operations he's doing on the map. Without context, we can't know whether changing data structure would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

To build on Adel Boutros answer/comment about the efficiency of iterating keys, you could encapsulate key iteration in a `Map` subclass or decorator.

Extending `HashMap` would give you a class to put the method in and keep map-specific code out of your method, so lowering complexity and making the code more natural to read.

Comment: This would mean my HashMap would need to be an instance of the extended HashMap and I would have to perform a cast from Map (if the map was declared as Map) to use the method. It does put the code in a neat place but probably wouldn't that usable

Comment: Yes. 
Or you can do `MyMapExtension m = new MyMapExtension(myMap);`
Or you can go with a decorator solution to wrap the map.
Both would read similarly to your original idea.

Comment: I see... I suppose the decorator option would prevent a new instance of the map being created so should be more efficient